# See reason why an Exception can be thrown (documentation)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exception, intellisense

I have this example method:

```
/// <summary>
///     Method to enforce that the type is an Enum.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"> Type.</typeparam>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException"> Thrown when type is not an Enum type. </exception>
public static void TypeIsEnum<T>(T type)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

When I hover over this method in visual studio, intellisense shows me some extra information, as shown below. [image: Intellisense method information]

Eventhough I documented the type of `exception` which can be thrown by the `TypeIsEnum` method with an explicit reason why it could be thrown, it doesn't show the reason in Intellisense. How can I show the reason of why an `exception` can be thrown in Intellisense?

Answer (score 2):

The intellisense that is shown is really dependant on the IDE being used. For example, Visual Studio Code shows this:

[image]

I don't have a copy to hand, but I wouldn't be surprised if Resharper shows much better detail too.

Comment: ReSharper's "Show Quick Documentation" command does indeed include the exception documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used Resharper that much yet, so thanks for pointing that out. Is there a way to override the default Intellisense used by VS (2015 Express) with the Quick Documentation of Resharper?